# Can not change icon for desktop icon

Tags: icons, ubuntu-mate

I can not change the icon for this desktop item.

I have some custom icons in their own directory that I use.

I can not open the desktop file for it either with my text editor like the other desktop files.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try to click on the icon button below first tab (in the left of *Name*)?

Comment: That is always first thing I do. I can not open the desktop file for it either with my text editor like the other desktop files. @NOrbert